# GCP windows VM does not work when logged off

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machines

I am running a Windows Server VM on GCP.
When logging in via Remote Desktop, I am starting certain applications which should actively run for a couple of hours.
But when closing my Remote Desktop Connection, all applications stop working.
How can I prevent this from happening?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep the session ongoing, you need to configure the RD Session Host time limits.
Open the group policy editor with: **Windows+R**, then type **gpedit.msc**, confirm with Enter.

Then in the management console, navigate to:

Computer Configuration
Administrative Templates
Windows Components
Remote Desktop Services
Remote Desktop Session Host
Session Time Limits

There one can adjust the settings:

Set time limit for disconnected sessions
Terminate sessions when time limits are reached.